# Indexing a tuple using a macro in Rust unexpected token

Tags: rust, tuples, rust-macros

I am trying to create a macro to perform a certain action for every element in a tuple in order to compensate for not being able to iterate over them.

I wrote some code that replicates my issue:

```rust
fn main() {
    let tuple = (1, 2);

    macro_rules! index_tuple {
        ($($i:literal),+) => {
            $(
                let t$i = tuple.$i;
            )+
        }
    }
    
    index_tuple!(0, 1);
}
```

[Rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6a1896ae3e1ad547eda4adfe52d02309)

---

But I have been met with the following error:

```
error: expected one of `:`, `;`, `=`, `@`, or `|`, found `0`
```

I have tried expanding the macro with CLion and the expanded macro worked perfectly fine so I am uncertain whether it is my fault or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust macros aren't simple text manipulation. So what your macro currently does is produce the tokens `'let' 't' '0' '=' 'tuple' '.' '0'` if you want to join them you have to use `quote!` which is notoriously underpowered and can't create new identifiers so it doesn't work here or [`paste::paste!`](https://docs.rs/paste/1.0.11/paste/):

```rust
use paste::paste;
fn main() {
    let tuple = (1, 2);

    macro_rules! index_tuple {
        ($($i:literal),+) => { paste!{
            $(
                let [<t $i>] = tuple.$i;
            )+
        }}
    }

    index_tuple!(0, 1);
}
```

Then you run into the next problem because of macro hygiene identifiers defined in declarative macros can't be accessed from outside the macro. Or in other words `t0` and `t1` will be as undefined after the macro as they are before. So your macro seems rather pointless, but maybe that's just from minimalizing it.

Comment: Using paste! worked brilliantly. Thank you!
Indeed, I got rid of pretty much everything in my original macro just to get a minimal working example with the same behaviour.